# Границы причастного оборота

Tags: синтаксис

Проходил тест на причастие. Встретил предложение: «Петя вышел к играющим во дворе ребятам», в котором требовалось найти причастный оборот. Я определил так: «играющим во дворе ребятам». В ответах: играющим во дворе. А как правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А как правильно?

В ответах правильно. Чтобы понять это, достаточно найти определяемое слово — в данном случае — ***ребята***: *Петя вышел к ребятам, играющим во дворе*. Само определяемое слово не относится к причастному обороту.

Comment: Ах,да! Верно! Знаю,что определяемое слово не относится к причастному обороту. Просто оно было в конце и я механически отнес его к причастному обороту. Посчитав "Петя" за определяемое слово. Впредь буду внимателен! ***Спасибо!***